# How can I display data returned from a PHP function when a HTML button is pressed

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax, laravel

I want to display in my page the fixtures generated from the PHP function but only when I press the "Generate Fixtures" button. I know that AJAX should be used but I can't pass the data from the function to the div in my HTML page.

### PHP code

```
 $teams = array("FC FCSB", "AFC Astra Giurgiu", "FC Dinamo 1948", "FC Viitorul 2009", "CSM Politehnica Iasi", "Universitatea Craiova", "FC Botosani", "CFR 1907 Cluj");
    $fixPair = new Fixture($teams);
    $schedule = $fixPair->getSchedule();
    $i = 1;
    foreach ($schedule as $rounds) {
        echo "<h5> Etapa " . $i . " </h5>";
        foreach ($rounds as $game) {
            echo "{$game[0]} vs {$game[1]}<br>";
        }
        echo "<br>";
        $i++;
    }
    echo "<hr>";
```

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
            $('.button').click(function(){
                var clickBtnValue = $(this).val();
                var ajaxurl = 'ajax.php',
                data =  {'action': clickBtnValue};
                $.post(ajaxurl, data, function (response) {
                    // Response div goes here.
                    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "Fixtures should be displayed here";
                    //alert("action performed successfully");
                });
            });
        });
```

```html
<script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js">
</script>
<input type="submit" class="button" name="insert" value="GENERATE FIXTURES" />
<div id="demo"></div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Update your event handler as:

```
$('.button').click(function(e){
    // Prevent form submit 
    e.preventDefault();

    var clickBtnValue = $(this).val();
    var ajaxurl = 'ajax.php',
    data =  {'action': clickBtnValue};
    $.post(ajaxurl, data, function (response) {
        // response variable stores all data received from ajax.php script

        // As you use jquery - you can select 
        // element by id with $("#id") selector
        $("#demo").html(response);
    });
});
```

Comment: Updated the handler, now what I need to do further?

Comment: Submit the form and see the results. Open developers console for debugging.